# Rolling back a set of db transactions upon exception in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, transactions

To start off with, [this GitHub project](https://github.com/Nerdenator/db_error_handling) contains the code I'm discussing and asking about in this post. It's a non-proprietary and short example of something that's actually being worked on by my team.

I'm working on a project where we use Django database transactions to do updates on a table in preparation for conversion to XML that can be used for business purposes. We have fixed formerly broken code by using `transaction.atomic()` context managers to make sure that errors are handled correctly. Each `UPDATE` statement sits within a context manager, which, in turn, sits within a function. There are three of these functions (`set_yes()`, `set_no()`, and `broken_query()`) called within another function (`bulk_set()`) in the program:

`models.py`

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import connection, DatabaseError, transaction
import pandas as pd

from django.db import models


class TestTable(models.Model):
    value1 = models.IntegerField()
    value2 = models.IntegerField()
    same = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True)


def setup_table():
    """
    sets up the basic table.
    several rows will have matching values, some won't.
    :return: None
    """
    row1 = TestTable(value1=1, value2=1)
    row1.save()

    row2 = TestTable(value1=2, value2=1)
    row2.save()

    row3 = TestTable(value1=56, value2=1)
    row3.save()

    row4 = TestTable(value1=10, value2=10)
    row4.save()


def set_yes():
    """
    sets "same" column on rows with matching value1 and value2 columns to "yes"
    :return: None
    """
    query = '''
        UPDATE db_app_testtable
        SET same = 'yes'
        WHERE value1 = value2
    '''
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
    except DatabaseError as ex:
        print "set_yes has error %s" % (ex)
        raise
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        print_table()


def set_no():
    """
    sets "same" column on rows with differing value1 and value2 columns to "no"
    :return: None
    """
    query = '''
        UPDATE db_app_testtable
        SET same = 'no'
        WHERE value1 != value2
    '''
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
    except DatabaseError as ex:
        print "set_no has error %s" % (ex)
        raise
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        print_table()


def broken_query():
    """
    a function meant to break. there is no column named 'different', so this should cause
    a DatabaseError to be thrown upon execution.
    :return: None
    """
    query = '''
        UPDATE db_app_testtable
        SET different = 'lol no'
        WHERE value1 = value2
    '''
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
    except DatabaseError as ex:
        print "broken_query has error %s" % (ex)
        raise
    finally:
        cursor.close()
...

def bulk_set():
    try:
        set_no()
        set_yes()
        broken_query()
    except Exception as gen_ex:
        print "Exception has occurred."
        raise
```

As you can see, `broken_query()` will not work, and this is by design. We are trying to design a code block that will rollback the operations done by `set_yes()` and `set_no()` if `broken_query()` fails, which it inevitably will.

Given the features of `django.db.transaction.atomic()`, is this possible? Reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic), it says, "*If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back.*" My question is, can this be extended to make other operations called in the same block of code roll back as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the same block of the `with atomic.transaction` if you call `raise Exception` you will have the transactions rolled back.

Comment: Understood, but that atomicity only extends to that transaction. I want to somehow make the transactions behave as a set so that if one fails, they all fail and all get rolled back.

Comment: So you need enclose all transactions in the atomic block.